# Question-ban timer, expiration of ban?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, profile-page, post-ban

The [page for the Question-Ban timer says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans)

> If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to **ask a new one 6 months** after your last question. If that question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking questions; if not, then the ban will be reinstated.

Is there any mechanism for which we can get that timer's value? I'm showing that I haven't asked a question for over a year ([since May 17, 2017](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295872/157251)) and that the question was upvoted (positive rep).

My reputation has also been doing pretty well, (top 6% this quarter).

[image]

This is over my [Stack Exchange account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/157251/evan-carroll?tab=reputation). In fact, every question since Aug 8 '12 has been positive.

I would like the Question-Ban timer to be prominently displayed in my profile dashboard, or someplace else I can easily find it.

[image]

I feel this is certainly on topic, here but feel free to migrate it to MSE if you'd like.

**Alternatively, if my feature can not be implemented -- how else can I find out this information?**

Comment: It's a feature request. I'm requesting the feature on my Stack Overflow account because it's tied together with my Stack Exchange account and then I'll at least know what I need to know. Seems totally within the realm of possibilities.

Comment: @Kevin see my update. This is **certainly** on topic. (but feel free to migrate it to MSE if you'd like)

Comment: @psubsee2003 I don't think that's a fair interpretation because it says "ask a new one 6 months after your *last question*". Not my "last question before the first question ban".

Comment: I didn't originally have this idea, but in order to make it on topic I had to integrate my need for the information into something StackOverflow-specific. I was able to do that in a way that should satisfy all members of StackOverflow for topicality. I'm probably the most skilled person at asking questions on this whole network.

Comment: @JonClements Those questions were asked here, not on Meta StackExchange. And, we're still trying to get them migrated to SuperUser where they're on topic (according to StackExchange staff). Last I checked the admin there said they were on topic and I should reask them, them admin here wanted to migrate them because then we'd keep answers (I agree). and the stackexchange employee wanted them asked on SuperUser. That's a lot of helpful input. No one has any criticisms of the questions, it's just finding where people agree they should belong.

Comment: Funny story: can't migrate questions to a site where you're question-banned. Otherwise, this would be on MSE. Where it would prevent you from asking questions for an even longer period of time. So... Count your blessings!

Comment: @Shog9 this feature request would be addressed by allowing users [see all their deleted posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356408/839601) no matter how old. We tried showing deleted posts up to 60 days old and this works for several years already and sky didn't fall. What's stopping us from trying a longer (indefinite) cut-off time? In the (extremely unlikely) case if things get bad we could simply return back to 60-days limit, can't we

Comment: Gotta be honest, @gnat... This is probably not the worst possible context for that suggestion, but it gives the worst possible context a run for its money.

Comment: Reopen and answer I had no idea I had deleted questions that was newer than 6 months and older than 60 days. Sometimes I wish this wasn't the most confusing and complex UI known to man. I have like a billion EXPs and I still can't manage to figure it out. Point their guys to https://ux.stackexchange.com/ If everyone works a little bit then maybe some day things will suck less.

Comment: @Shog9 your money talks make it sound like some serious development effort. That feels somewhat confusing because if I understand it right, we're talking about something like changing "60" to "6000" somewhere in config file or in code

Comment: @gnat: He's saying that asking for such a feature, in the context of this post by a user who has Evan's history, is not helping your case.

Comment: @NicolBolas I see. Request to change 60 to 6000 (after several years of successful testing) needs help. While wasting months of dev time on senseless stuff like Documentation is okay without any help

Comment: @NicolBolas I bring forward my concerns and I hope that others -- employees and otherwise -- have the professionalism to address them as they sit: how can I, as a user who only sees upvoted questions know when I can next ask another question to be upvoted? That sounds like a reasonable UX request.

Comment: @gnat: You can't just stop all feature development and throw everything into burning down [the list](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100531-00/?p=13873).  Then there would be no feature development at all and your product would stagnate.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: Yes, that's my point.  They don't have the developer resources to spare, *because* the product is already just about stagnating.

Comment: So if they add this to the lengthy list of things that aren't getting done, the product will finally stop stagnating. I think they have a pos open for community manager. You have my endorsement.

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question, because it is a valid request. It might be declined (as it is), but the request is still valid.

Comment: @Kevin take a look at the linked question, this feature was requested about half year ago and has gained over 100 upvotes. Same request [at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/165773) is there for many years, it has got over 800 upvotes and 19 bounties from about 15 users, including moderators. That's pretty solid demand for a simple easy reversible change of config parameter in an already thoroughly tested feature...

Comment: ...and that's quite a different context than capriciously asking to help a single banned user, don't you think? We can only guess why @Shog9 has chosen to defuse this into tangential discussion about troublesome history of the OP while he is very well aware of that broader context. (maybe it's just difficult to quit worshipping Atwood's guidance which instructs ["Don't Let Them Tell You What to Do"](https://blog.codinghorror.com/listen-to-your-community-but-dont-let-them-tell-you-what-to-do/):)

Comment: @gnat: That isn't entirely unreasonable guidance, actually.  If every site did what its users wanted every time they asked, then every site would quickly converge on some kind of quasi-Facebook-esque thing and we'd have no variety.  Not that that isn't happening already...

Comment: that's a totally reasonable guidance @Kevin - no wonder that they religiously follow it by ignoring everything asked by a community

Comment: @gnat If you ever run moderator, you have my vote. You know what's going on around here.

Comment: You wanna make an argument for easier access to deleted posts, @gnat, then go make an argument for easier access to deleted posts. But MSE has the most relaxed q-ban rules on the entire network, and Evan *still* managed to exceed the ban threshold 10x over. Seeing more deleted posts does jack for *this scenario*, unless you're seriously making the argument that we should give folks with a proven trackrecord of posting massively unpopular questions an easy way to count down to their next opportunity to do so, in which case no we shouldn't and that alone is good reason to not do what you ask.

Comment: You're the one who said "six months". The only thing it's going to force me to do is write down my last question in my profile so I know it after it's been wrongly closed, and I'm just asking you do it for me. =( Not to mention, most of my posts aren't massively downvoted. You've got people you actively pay that have got posts with more downvotes than my **entire profile** https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309746/157251

Comment: It's like you muddled the a popularity contest that is meta, with the privilege to get support on the network: "a lot of people are dedicated to downvoting you, so you're not popular enough for to ask questions here." You've removed any burden to find wrongdoing and have taken a moral stance on my posts without ever treating voting as a moral issue.

Comment: The six-month thing is a "second chance" for folks who made an honest mistake and can do better, @Evan. You've had numerous second chances, and wasted them all. If you want asking privileges on MSE again, start *answering* some of those support questions and *helping* people who haven't had the sort of experience that you've mostly squandered up to now - show you can contribute something worthwhile on an ongoing basis.

Comment: @Shog9 you realize for the quarter I'm in the top 100 on Meta.StackExchange.com too? There are only 97 people who have done a better job answering questions... (I'm also pretty busy answering the technical questions on the network, I was #1 on DBA.StackExchange.com for 2017 **for the entire year**)

Comment: Yeah, and that's up 2000-some places over the previous quarter... And there are only 1600-some positive ranks this quarter so far. Two quarters in six months, so maybe aim to stay in the top 100 for two consecutive quarters instead of counting down the days...

Comment: Why would I put in effort at all, if you can't tell me that even upon achieving that feat the question ban will expire? I have no reason to trust Stack Exchange -- originally it was just "time in a penalty box" now it's maybe if I stay in the top-100 for 6 months? I'm there now. By your own numbers there are only 1600 people making positive contributions and 1500 of them aren't as a good as me? It's always a shifting a goal post with Evil Inc.,

Comment: @EvanCarroll The post ban doesn't "expire".  You're allowed to ask a question *even though you're below the quality threshold* if it has been six months since your last question.  But it doesn't mean you're just instantly back to where you started.  You just get to ask that *one* question (unless you get back above the quality threshold).  Think of it more like a 6 month rate limit than a ban (the name didn't change when it was changed from actually being a ban, hence the confusion).

Comment: @EvanCarroll Of those 1500 people with positive contributions, the majority of them have posted ~1 post.  SE sites in general, but in particular meta sites, have a small number of active contributors that post a lot, and then a lot of people that either don't post or *very* rarely post.  It takes just a small handful of posts with only a small handful of votes to be in the top few percent.  In fact, you have only *one* positively scored answer in the past *five years*.  Do you really think that *one* good answer, and 5 poor answers in that time frame is actually a sign that you're doing well?

Comment: I wanna make an argument about what is so scary or difficult in trying to change config value from "60" days to "600" or "6000" @Shog9 - assuming that this change can easily be reverted if we discover that things go wrong, be it because of Evan or anyone else doesn't matter. As for arguments in favor of trying it these were already made [at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/165773), with 800+ upvotes, 22 answers and 19 bounties from 15 users (including multiple moderators)

Comment: There's nothing hard about any of this, @gnat. I can change site settings randomly all day long with barely any effort. 1 second wait-times between questions! 5000 binding close votes per person at 3 rep! 1 question per page! Auto-wiki at 1 edit! Presumably there should be a reason behind changes beyond "it's easy to make numbers into different numbers!"

Comment: presumably there's no other reason to do this... except those listed in my previous comment: "800+ upvotes, 22 answers and 19 bounties from 15 users (including multiple moderators) "

Answer (score 12):

There is no "question ban timer". There's just a ban. You, like the vast, vast majority of people to encounter the ban, ignored most of [the guidance on that page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) (including the title). I'll quote the most relevant portions here:

> ## Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?
>
> At Stack Exchange, [asking questions is a privilege, not a right](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/04/asking-better-questions/). If a user cannot demonstrate, after asking a reasonable number of questions, that their contributions are making the site better (or at very least, not making it *worse*) then they will be blocked from asking further questions until they *have* demonstrated their ability to contribute positively.
>
> Users who are banned from asking questions see the following error message when trying to post a new question:
>
> > We are no longer accepting questions from this account. See [the Help Center](/help/question-bans) to learn more.
>
> Question bans do not affect other privileges, such as commenting or voting, and there is no indication to the rest of the community that a particular user has been banned.
>
> ### How can I get out of a question ban?
>
> Begin by **improving [your existing questions](/users/current?tab=questions)**: do as much as possible to make them clear, specific and on-topic.
>
> The ban will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines that your positive contributions outweigh the cost of those questions which were poorly received.
>
> #### Stack Exchange cannot lift question bans by request.
>
> **Edit [*all* of your questions](/users/current?tab=questions)**, paying special attention to those that score 0 or less. All questions are expected to be useful to future visitors, so put effort into writing with proper grammar and spelling, formatting your post so it can be read easily, and providing as much detail as possible about your problem and what you have already tried. Then write a title that summarizes your problem so that others encountering the exact same issue can find it. Reading your question out loud to yourself can help you understand what it sounds like to others.

If you don't feel like doing all that, it's ok - most people who encounter this message don't. **That's why the system exists** - so that we don't have to keep getting questions from people who aren't willing to follow the suggestions for improving their existing posts much less apply them to new questions.

The six-month allowance exists - as implied by its description at the end of that article following a lengthy list of additional resources - for the sake of folks who've tried everything and just haven't quite squeaked by, but have none the less learned to write effective questions while doing so. It's not a quota or a right, it's a token gesture for a very, very small handful of people who can actually benefit from it.

None of this applies to you on Meta Stack Exchange: in nearly 8 years, you've made [precisely one edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/59454/revisions) to one of your downvoted questions; in fact, you've made only two edits to *any* of your questions on MSE since August of 2010. If you're going to ignore 90% of the guide, you might as well just ignore the rest.

Comment: So if I edit those posts (which I can't delete), and nothing changes with the votes on those questions but I continue asking good questions (as 7 of them since August 2010 are), do the ban expire?

Comment: I have no idea; depends how good you are at editing. If you can convince half as many people to upvote your posts as you've convinced to downvote them, the ban will certainly be lifted - but that's on you. If you just go around fixing typos, nothing will change.

Comment: So we're back to banning people for being unpopular with the altright

Comment: You can be unpopular and helpful, or popular and unhelpful... But you can't be both unpopular and unhelpful.

Comment: So you agree they're different, only one them should be penalized, and this inept platform only assess a conflation of the two such that someone less helpful but more popular can ask questions and someone more helpful and less popular - as your data screams - can't.

Comment: Yeah... See, the problem here is that you want to not be banned for being unpopular, but you also don't want to be helpful. I'd be ok banning popular but unhelpful people too, but I don't have a good way to do it and it wouldn't help you anyway.