# Please make it known for the users, when their Q&A ban expires

Tags: feature-request, post-ban

Seeing the questions in the meta VtC/VtR queue, I think the OPs are right that they should have at least known it.

Alternatively, they should have also known the numerical counting of their Q/A record. Simply to know, where they are and how many upvotes should they collect, how many post should they fix and so on.

It would work also as a "triage" functionality: roughly those users would work hardly to fulfill the requirements, who seem more salvageable. I.e. if you see that you need only 2 undeleted and upvoted posts, then you will work likely more hardly, if your account seem totally hopeless. And we need exactly these users.

The worst if they don't know anything: it expels them, and doesn't motivate them to improve their posts.

Comment: Not saying I don't think this could be an improvement, but the argument can be made that they had plenty of opportunities and motivation **before** getting into the ban.

Comment: They're warned when they're about to *hit* the q-ban.  The fact that they can ask a question every six or so months is a courtesy to them, and not a guarantee.  [But don't take *my* word for it.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368473/1079354)

Comment: @yivi On this reasoning, they could be also expelled from the SO after their first ban. Reductio ad absurdum. Instead of destroying and killing everybody, you should consider thinking about, how to motivate them.

Comment: _"destroying and killing everybody"_. Yeah, I'm out of here

Comment: @peterh I'm one of the cases where a question ban worked. It helped me read the site rules, search for existing answers, and improve my contributions with the goal of "do better"

Comment: @Makoto It is not enough and not clear. They need numerical information, like in the reps. If you want to close/reopen questions, you know exactly, where are you on they way to the 3000. The same should go for the Q&A ban.

Comment: @yivi Yes, that was the point of your comment, in my opinion. No information, no help, just ban and punishment. This is a very bad algorithm for a site living from its visitors.

Comment: There isn't any numerical information for bans, though.  This is *intentionally* hidden to prevent users from gaming the system.  If a user wishes to improve their question, we here on Meta would welcome them with open arms and provide them with what they needed to actually improve what they could.  If a user doesn't at least take that step, I'm not so certain that numerical information would help, either.

Comment: @Makoto There is no way to game such a system, more exactly there is no more way than gaming the reputation system, which is possible but too hard. Typically, holding back information about your exact position in a system is an opressive thing.

Comment: I disagree with the premise that "we need exactly these users." We need users who are willing to improve their content, regardless of whether it allows them to ask more questions or not. Ideally, anyone with bad questions or answers, banned or not, should still improve any bad content they've added to the site. As [Shog says,](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368473/7795130) "If you don't feel like doing all that, it's ok... That's why the system exists - so that we don't have to keep getting questions from people who aren't willing to follow the suggestions for improving their existing posts"

Comment: @peterh I see you’ve never worked in risk management.  I have, on Wall St. Do you think anti money laundering officers publicize the patterns of transactions they look for to detect people trying to launder money? Do you think brokers publish the times of day they calculate client’s market exposure? Do you think the OCC tells banks the exact methods they will use during an audit? Do you think Ernst and Young tell their clients where in their books they’re going to scrutinize? The position you stated is obtuse. Protecting your risk methodology isn’t oppressive, it’s literally best practice.

Comment: @DanBron Posting bad posts is not money laundering. They require motivation to improve, and not extermination.

Comment: @DanBron Btw, also you are thinking only in punishments, retorsions, bans. This is a very good example of the toxic atmosphere of this whole system.

Comment: _"Instead of destroying and killing everybody, you should consider thinking about, how to motivate them"_  You do realise that people are volunteering their own free time here?

Comment: @Epodax Yes, just like me - and just like the newbies whose first experience with the site is a Q/A ban, even before they could learn the rules. And note: I don't ask about to not punish them - *I suggest to say them, how long are they punished*.

Comment: Newbies are expected to learn the rules before posting, not doing so is a fault of their own, and I'm fairly certain that when people are banned/punished that it tells them how long.

Comment: @Epodax *"Newbies are expected to learn the rules before posting"* <- Yeah, just like you are expected to read all the ToS of all the websites you visit, including its interpretation and possible side-results on the law of the country where it is working... *I'm fairly certain that when people are banned/punished that it tells them how long.* <- No, nothing says them, it is kept secret as to "prevent to game the system" as you could have learned it from the numerous meta posts complaining this. Yes, it successfully prevents to "game the system" by *improving their posts*...

Comment: And if you break the ToS you can be punished as well, and are we talking about how long until they are banned or when banned/punished already, how long until it expires? - regardless, saying we are evil because we uphold the rules are like saying that countries are evil because they punish people who do crime.

Comment: @Epodax This only explains, why the SE/SO can do it. The post is about, what the SE/SO should do. Explaining why can we do something badly is not an explanation, why we don't do better. Particularly, if the current practice is an evil one.

Comment: If you think it's evil to have a set of standards / not hold everyone's hand then we very much disagree and I doubt any further discussion will lead anywhere.

Comment: @Epodax As I explained, I consider the current practice evil, because it unneededly harms people, and harms the site, while it could also fix the people and improve the site, on the same effort.

Comment: @peterh: "*evil*", "*destroying and killing everybody*": Can you discuss this matter *without* descending into cartoonish hyperbole? It really makes it difficult to take your argument seriously.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes - I think below your answer it can happen. All it depends on, that the comments show open hostility or rational arguments.

Comment: But the question ban always 'expires' (read: gives you another chance at a question) 6 months after your last question... So 'how long' isn't really what you need to display. What's needed is a 'are you banned?' banner. And SO has already clearly said they won't do that to prevent people gaming the system and knowing the exact limits. I don't see a way, between that constraint and how the system currently works, to have what you want....

Comment: @Patrice Also the 6 month isn't shown, and maybe it isn't even public. They need to find it from rumors. Well, it seems I disagree with the SO. Being this system theirs, unlikely that my suggestion will be ever implemented - however, also they have to bear the consequences of their this bad decision (and the many goodstanding newbies whose first experience about the site is a slap in the face).

Comment: @peterh the free question every 6 months is very public. It's part of the dupe canonical for 'I am banned, what do I do?' so with a tidbit of research a user can find it. And I think we'd disagree this is a bad decision. We already see enough people acting in bad faith on meta when it comes to the ban... I would be surprised showing specifically how many upvotes you'd need to get out wouldn't cause more issues of sock puppetting/fraudulent accounts. I get what you're trying to do, and I agree the ban is a bit of a touchy subject when it comes to new user's experience...

Comment: But I believe the downsides of your suggestion will outweigh its benefits. Maybe there is another solution that will be better than the one we have now... But I personally don't believe showing metrics about the ban is it.

Comment: @Patrice Most of the Qbanned users won't ever visit the meta. They will silently leave. With them, the site loses also the content, in most cases, acceptable content, what they could have created, if they hadn't been expelled on for them unclear reasons. I also disagree that they would act in bad faith. They act in the belief that this site would be an usual web forum, where correct and clear questions are not expected, a professionalist writing style is not expected and anybody is free to initiate an unbound discussion about any loosely specified topic.

Comment: @Patrice It is not okay here, but they aren't doing it in bad faith. It would be bad faith happen, and the punishment would be okay, if they would act knowing the rules. But they don't know. An example case, from which the post ban is okay, I would show [this example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381321/1783163). In the following weeks, I will follow his posts and I will try to motivate him to improve. But if he acts first time, I think he shouldn't be punished.

Comment: @peterh the issue becomes one of scalability as well, as sad as it is. If showing the thresholds create so much work for mods (with sock puppets, harassment for that **last** upvote a new user need, etc) they can't keep up, some bad faith users will be left able to ask, and the site may end up dropping significantly in quality from that. It's honestly hard to say without specific numbers.... Would definitely be an interesting experiment (it may help more than it hurts... I am not convinced but I can be wrong) I just don't know how to conduct it, and I am pretty sure Stack won't try it out:/

Comment: @peterh I agree. I haven't reviewed that particular user's questions, but if said user is willing to improve, to follow guidance, to work through understanding our sometimes esoteric rules, they definitely should be helped as much as we can. I will never say no to that. The question is truly how much good vs how much bad would come out of it, and how to prove which one will be dominant. For such a big change I don't see it being judged worth it until there are some hard numbers proving it would help. And I don't see a way to prove it, short of doing it. Kind of a catch22

Answer (score 17):

Q&A bans do not expire. They're not even technically "bans"; they're a long form of time restrictions. You get to make one post new every 6 months.

As for whether the system should tell them when they get to post again... no. We do not want users waiting with baited breath for that moment when they get to post again. That is not conducive to getting good questions.

> Simply to know, where they are and how many upvotes should they collect, how many post should they fix and so on.

Absolutely not. That's basically telling them how the system works. And we don't do that specifically to keep people from trying to game the system. We *do not want* people to be counting votes to try to stay barely above board. We don't want people doing the bare minimum, so we don't let them know what that is.

> And we need exactly these users.

No, we don't. We need users who will use our site correctly *the first time*. Not users who are counting votes to stay above water.

Getting a ban is *not easy*; you have to fail repeatedly and significantly in order to do so. Getting out of a ban should likewise not be easy.

Comment: Are you implying that people getting a Q/A ban are trying to "game the system"? I think they simply don't know enough well, how to ask here. They are thinking this is a common forum system, where anybody can ask any crap, they don't need to write correctly, they don't need to ask clear questions, instead they are free to initiate unbound discussions. Having the option to adapt, they would likely adapt (the few who doesn't, is okay if they get ban), but they don't have this option after the ban was already applied.

Comment: @peterh: "*Are you implying that people getting a Q/A ban are trying to "game the system"?*" No, I'm out-right stating that, if people know how the system works, *some of them* will try to game it. Not everyone is a bad actor, but you can't design a system that pretends bad actors don't exist.

Comment: The rules, how to get all the privileges on the site, are well-known and yes, they can be tricked. But this trickery is too hard to become a serious problem. The easiest way to get privileges is to write posts, and not tricking anything. Having this openness is one of the largest attractive power of the SE sites. Knowing, how far away you are from vtc/vtr, or from the 10k, is the largest motivator here, imho. What makes the rules of the Q&A ban different? The easiest to get out a Q&A ban should be to improve the posts.

Comment: I have to disagree, I got a question ban a long time ago, mostly because I was doing a time sensitive project on the Pi 3 which had no documentation at the time. A lot of people considered my questions poor, but few explained how those questions could be improved.

I didn't have the time to understand what was wrong with my questions so i kept asking, got benned. Started asking in the pi stack exchange instead, started getting downvotes there too. So I went to the pi forums where people were finally patient enough to explain to me where and how I was messing up.

Comment: @Makogan: I'm not sure what your story has to do with anything I've said. That a user might manage to become a useful and productive contributor to SO in time is fine; that's why the "ban" is just a restriction rather than a true ban. But that doesn't change anything I've said here about the potential to game the ban system if it is more explicit about the details of exactly which things will cause it to be lifted.